# How about a higher-order function called struggle?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, erlang

imagine your wife asks you to go buy some Campion flowers. as it’s a rare kind of flower you’re not sure if you can find it the flower shop next door. so you’ll have to check every single flower shop in the town and ask for them campions. But the fact is some of the flower shops have public phone numbers and you can ask them on the phone. some of them have websites and some of them you have to walk inside.

So you start your quest from the easiest possible solutions. the point is you check every single flower shop in a unique way, as the way you talk to them or the path you walk to get to the guy. these are several functions if we talk code-wise; one function per shop.

So in the programming world, you’ll have to write 10 different query function for 10 possible solutions. The next move is to try every possible solution in the list one by one and as soon as you get a positive answer/reply/return, you’ll stop the quest and present the answer.

I thought it’s a routine, like filter and map and reducers most likely, and i believe i’m right enough.

So how about having something like this?

in erlang:

```
-export([struggle/2]).

struggle(Input, Solutions) ->
    struggle(Input, Solutions, false).

struggle(_, [], false) ->
    false;
struggle(Input, [Solution|OtherSolutions], false) ->
    struggle(Input, OtherSolutions, Solution(Input));
struggle(_, _, Answer) ->
    Answer.
```

or in javascript:

```
function struggle(input, solutions)
{
    let strgl = (input, solutions, acc) => {
        if (solutions.length === 0 && acc === undefined) return undefined;
        if (acc === undefined) return strgl(input, solutions.slice(1), solutions[0](input));
        return acc;
    };
    return strgl(input, solutions, undefined);
}
```

don't you think it's general enough to be a built-in higher-order function?

PS: the code is working fine and there's no need to fix it. the question is, why isn't it a built-in function?

Comment: So a bit like `Promise.race` ?

Comment: I don't know Erlang, but are you looking for [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)?

Comment: `solutions.map(f => f(input)).find(ans => ans !== undefined);`

Comment: @4castle, no `Array.prototype.find` and `Array.prototype.filter` are only good when all of the data is one place or at least share one data structure (to concat them for having one data source). i'm talking about a situation where you need different function bodies which one of them may be `ans => ans !== undefined`, but not all of them.

Comment: @T4rk1n somehow but not exactly. because `Promise.race` executes all of the possible solutions at the same time and returns the first `resolve` it gets from those async called promises. here we need an order/priority.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Isn't `solutions` an array of functions? My code calls each of those functions with `input` as the parameter, and then finds the first result that's not `undefined`.

Comment: @4castle oh my bad! didn't see the `map(f => f(input))` part. but still.. this is going to run all of the functions and then choose. while we could stop revoking the rest, once we found a good return value, using my version of it. right? but i agree it's just a matter of performance. otherwise no difference in output value.

Comment: That's true. It will run all of the functions. Now that I understand what you're trying to accomplish, I can try to write an answer.

Answer (score 4):

What is the exact problem?

```
strugle(Input, Solutions) ->
  lists:any(fun(X) -> X(Input) end, Solutions).
```

It is Erlang essentials. Or if you wish to return first non-false value.

```
strugle(Input, Solutions) ->
  any_non_false(fun(X) -> X(Input) end, Solutions).

any_non_false(F, L) ->
  try lists:any(fun(X) ->
      case F(X) of
        false -> false;
        Y -> throw({return, Y})
      end
    end, L)
  catch {return, X} -> X end.
```

Comment: This will only work when the functions return `true` or `false`. I believe OP wants to be able to return any value from the function and return the first non `false` value. At least that's what OP's Erlang and JS code does (the JS code returns the first non `undefined` value).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very much like [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), except that your desired return value is the first truthy value that `find` sees, and not the element that produced the truthy value.

You could use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accomplish this:

```
function struggle(input, solutions) {
  return solutions.reduce((ans, solution) =>
    ans !== undefined ? ans : solution(input)
  , undefined);
}
```

Written imperatively, this would be like:

```
function struggle(input, solutions) {
  for (const solution of solutions) {
    const ans = solution(input);
    if (ans !== undefined) {
      return ans;
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

This doesn't sound like it needs to be a built-in function, because it's not general enough. There's two steps here: (1) mapping the solutions, and (2) testing if the value is acceptable. Built-in JavaScript functions tend to be extremely general purpose. More specific functions are a better fit for utility libraries.

Comment: you know your reducer version of it takes redundant steps of comparing, even after finding the answer. i know there's probably no real performance impact in doing a simple `ans !== undefined` call, but it's redundant anyways, and i know the problem is there's no `break` for this kind of loops, as there's no `break` at all in non-imperative codes.

Comment: Right. Functional languages usually support short-circuiting via laziness. JavaScript is eagerly evaluated, so you would need to write it using some imperative feature of JavaScript, a library that does it for you, or using recursion as you did initially.

Answer (score 1):

In Scheme you could write your code this way:

```scm
// some from SRFI-1, also called ormap in some dialects
(define (struggle input solutions)
  (some (lambda (f) (f input)) solutions))
```

It seems JavaScript got [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and Erlang has [`lists:any/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#any-2) but both are flawed by that they don't return the truthy value but only `true` so you only get to know if it found an answer and not what the answer was.

In JS it's simple to make a version of `some` that works the same as Scheme. I'm not sure about Erlang.